# How do conservation of energy and induced emf reconcile when using a time varying field on a stationary conductor?

Tags: electromagnetic-induction

There are generally two ways to induce emf - By moving a coil in a constant magnetic field or by using a time-varying magnetic field on a stationary coil.
It is easy to understand that in the case of induction by motion, the electrical energy we obtain in the coil is the mechanical energy we used to move it through the field. But where does the electrical energy in the coil come from in the case of a stationary coil in a time-varying field?
I do not want the force considerations here (unless necessary to explain it), just a simple reconciliation of the law of conservation of energy with induction in a stationary coil.

Comment: Where does the time-varying field come from?

Comment: In the case of the time varying field, you're doing work somewhere else to make the field change in time.

Comment: So the work we do in order to change the field is what appears as the energy here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's basically the same thing:  The energy you obtain in the coil is the energy used to produce the time-varying field.  The exact process depends on what is producing the field.

A simple example might be a rotating magnet.  You need to put energy into the magnet to make it rotate.  Free of friction and other influences (and ignoring any EM radiation it would produce for now), the energy will remain in the magnet and it will rotate indefinitely.

If you draw power from a stationary coil in the field, it will oppose the field and place a drag on the magnet's rotation.  The total energy drawn from the coil cannot exceed the rotational energy that was initially in the magnet.

Comment: Thanks for this, this seemed the most logical solution to this problem I had been tussling with for some days.